# I need help with shade smooth

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode, vertices

I'm making an ant in Blender, but there is a problem above the jaw when I use Shade Smooth [image]

[image]

Comment: Hello recalculate the normals in Edit mode (Shift N), make sure that you don't have overlapping vertices (M > Merge by Distance) and check if you don't have inner faces